# What do you call a letter saying that you are amenable of a request?

Tags: single-word-requests, letter-writing

I am writing a letter to express my acceptance of a request from my employer. Their request is for me to stay longer in the company because the supposed effectivity of my resignation is 30 days from the filing date. In exchange of accepting the request, I don't have to pay the cash bond they imposed because of me not finishing the contract. What do you call this type of letter? And what are the usual content of the body of the letter?

Comment: @rajeem - I've re-read your question several times and I'm still not sure I understand: You've offered to resign; your employer has accepted your resignation; now you want to write a letter confirming your resignation?  Did I get that right?  If that's NOT what you meant to say, could you try to rephrase your question - perhaps break it into separate sentences.

Comment: "Extend the effectivity of my resignation?" I'm sorry, but I didn't understand the above phrase. Could you please expound, rajeem_cariazo?

Comment: My understanding: Rajeem has resigned from a position prior to the end of his contract; his early resignation means his employer is allowed to keep the cash bond Rajeem put up when he signed the employment contract. His employer has offered to release the bond (not make him pay) if Rajeem agrees to continue working for another 30 days. He now needs to write a letter stating that he agrees to these terms and wants to know what such a letter is called and what it should contain. Frankly, it sounds more like a legal question than one of language, but perhaps not.

Comment: @Matthew I'm sorry if you misunderstood my question. I have to pay the cash bond because of not finishing the two-year contract. If I stay longer in the company to give my employer enough time to find a replacement to my position, then the cash bond I supposedly need to pay will be waived.

Comment: @Rajeem Yes, that's what I wrote. Perhaps I was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `Letter of Agreement` would be most correct, with `Memorandum of Understanding` a close second.

As I understand it you're basically looking for a letter that outlines that you've both agreed to a modified contract, and at least in the legal arena those terms are what seem to be most common.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, where you are receiving a benefit from your acceptance of a change in terms, you should mention both the change and the benefit.  Something like "Your letter says that I will remain until xxx and that you will not require payment of the cash bond.  I agree to this" though you should where possible repeat the important words of their letter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident that there is a specific term for this type of *letter*. It may be better to look for an adjective that fits the scenario. The relevant words for the situation appear to be:

- termination
- resignation
- agreement
- contract
- deal
- compliance
- exemption
- confirmation

And so on. Not all of these terms apply to *your* letter — as opposed to your employer's letters — but I would describe the scenario as:

- You submitted your **resignation**
- The pending effective resignation date is 30 days prior to the date mentioned in your **contract**
- Your employer is offering you a **deal** for an **exemption** to the cash bond portion of your contract in exchange for delaying your pending resignation date
- They require a written **agreement** of the exemption and delay

I am not entirely positive this helps but I don't really understand why you need to call the letter anything. This seems heavily legal in nature and if you need a *legal* term, we cannot help you because we do not want to be liable for handing out bad or incorrect legal advice.

If you just need to talk about the letter you have to write, I would call it an "acceptance letter" or a "written agreement". Another alternative would be "written confirmation".

One thing to note is that "letter" could be part of the problem here. Typically, the desire for writing these sorts of letters is to provide a paper trail in case something goes wrong in the future. These paper trails don't really care if it is a *letter*; they just need some form of *written* consent. This is also referred to as "in writing": "I need that in writing" or "Please offer us an agreement in writing."

If none of this helps, I suggest finding someone else who has worked for the same company and ended up in the same scenario to find out what *they* called the letter. Chances are high that other people have encountered this before. And you could always ask your company's legal department. Terms are terms and are not likely to change from place to place.

Answer (score -1):

The term you are looking for is:

> **Acceptance Letters**

Also, here are some tips on writing such a letter:

> Acceptance Letters
>
> How to write an acceptance letter:
>   Even if you have accepted verbally, it is smart to write an acceptance letter to formally accept the offer and to confirm the details.
>
> Be gracious
>   When accepting a request, job, promotion, appointment, public office, gift, etc.
>
> Thank the person, business, organization, etc. when you begin your letter.
>
> Briefly identify what it is that you are accepting.
>   For example, “This is a wonderful opportunity for me, and I am happy to accept the position as associate director of sales.”
>
> Recheck for errors.
>   For job offers and the like, the acceptance letter may become part of a company’s permanent file for you, so make sure that it is well-worded and free of embarrassing grammatical or other errors.
>
> Close your letter by restating your appreciation for being offered the job, request, award, gift, etc.

these tips are not mine, they are taken from a [letter-writing site](http://www.writeexpress.com/acceptance.htm)

Comment: I don't think this is an acceptance letter, really, because it's more of a legal letter. Like a contract, he probably needs to specify what each party is agreeing to, clearly stating the terms of his acceptance.